# Can you set an automatic Xcode bot to build from a git tag?

Tags: xcode

We tag our git repo with dev/qa/stage tags. Is there a way to build an Xcode bot that will run whenever the tag is updated? Or can we manually run the bot on a particular tag, rather than a branch?

When I try to make the bot URL point to https://github.com/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/tree/qa, I get a 404 error, even though I can navigate to that URL in my browser.

Comment: Would like to be able to do this as well. (set up a bot that builds a specific git tag). But the answer to your second question is that it's a Github URL, and git isn't aware of Github functionality, which is why it does not work.